# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT with Lightsail Ubuntu Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh

I no longer have access to lightsail because I idiot followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04-de) tutorial here. Anyway, I have a snapshot of my instance. So I started the instance and attached the static IP to the new instance and adjusted the virtual host file and the .htaccess from Wordpress. The problem I have is that when I try to open the page trough the domain I get the error message "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  mysite
ServerAlias mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress

<Directory /var/www/wordpress>

Options FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo

DirectoryIndex index.php

Require all granted

</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/wordpress/wp-content>

Options FollowSymLinks

Require all granted

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by myself. In case anyone is curious.
In the Lightsail settings of my instance under network, port 443 was not open.